# Интеграция getresponse c drupal 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, интеграция

Скачал плагин с офф сайта, установил, и сразу же в консоли выдает ошибку:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onchange' of null
    at window.onload (js_my_file:119)

Comment: Никто с такой проблемой не сталкивался?

Comment: ?.........................